# java 8 UUID mismatch on inheriting from parent model

Tags: java, java-8, aem, uuid

In parent JAVA model I am generating UUID like so, in a loop since there are multiple items:

```
    @PostConstruct
protected void init() {
    list = IntStream.range(0, items)
            .boxed()
            .map(idx -> "item" + idx)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

In child model, I want to inherit this id for each iteration. I have used the below resource adaptation:

```
Resource parentResource = resource.getParent();
ParentClass parentClass = parentResource.adaptTo(parentClass.class);
parentId = parentClass.getId();
```

The issue is, the child inherits the next UUID generated! How can I persist one UUID from parent to child, then change in next iteration?

Comment: Please elaborate: "_In child model, I want to inherit this id for each iteration_", what iteration? "_The issue is, the child inherits the next UUID generated!_", what next `UUID`? There is only one UUID in your example

Comment: @smac89 UUID generates a random id every time, so the issue is, in child model, next id gets generated, whereas I want to use the same id as parent in one iteration, then in next iteration, I want next random UUID to be generated, and inherited by child

Comment: Is this ID supposed to identify the resource or an instance of the model? Can you post complete examples of the model classes? How do you use the value? Do you need it to be the same across multiple AEM instances?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour since you are calling `parentResource.adaptTo` method in the child, which will again trigger the `@PostConstruct` method of the parent.

What you can do is persist/save the UUID as a property in the CRX/de database for a specific resource.

Another approach you can consider is to send data from parent model to child via request, i.e. `request.setAttribute(...)`